# Google Script XML Parsing Error: Cannot find function

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I uploaded a number of XML files to my Google Drive. They are set to be shared with anyone on the web. I made a list of the links in a Google Sheet. (Picture below.)

[image: Picture of Google Sheet with list of XML files]

I am trying to parse the XML files using a [Script from GitHub](https://github.com/ConfidentCannabis/sheets-script-xpath). (See below for full script.) However when I call the function in cell F2 of the sheet with `=xPath("@url",E2)`, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getRootElement in object
>   https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1heoXLD9uQOZitQHTuhS3xuM8oZduQPZJ.
>   (line 49).

The @url attribute definitely exists in the XML file. But, I don't know why the function can't find it. [The link to the XML file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1heoXLD9uQOZitQHTuhS3xuM8oZduQPZJ/view).

[An editable copy of the Google Sheet with the script is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B5L9JOuW3oYmrAubMtiZC01-R4aoOMw-IJcaPzmW3Zg/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the Google Script from GitHub:

```js
/**
 * Add simple XPath XML parsing to google scripts. Essentially be able to
 * use the xpath notation that works in the IMPORTXML formula but from
 * script code instead.
 *
 * NOTE: this is a GOOGLE SCRIPT library - this WILL NOT WORK outside of
 * google scripts because it uses the apps script XML Service
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 *   In your script, go to Resources -> Libraries then enter the following
 *   Project Key or Script ID in the 'Find a Library' box.
 *
 *   Project Key: M1YVJTfv66XpF5AoIeE9zsAopJxr71Kma
 *   Script ID: 1EyZK520ihKS4JWE1B47Ra0fU4B4m9vAHX0FWMZ50xNUJsU_R9VRIsqf3
 *
 */

/**
 * Returns the value (or list of values) at the given path in
 * the given xmlFile
 *
 * Example:
 *
 *     <xml>
 *       <foo>
 *         <bar>
 *           <baz what='wrong'>thing1</baz>
 *           <baz what='test'>thing2</baz>
 *         </bar>
 *       </foo>
 *       <fizz>buzz</fizz>
 *      </xml>
 *
 *     var xml = readRemoteXML('https://test-xml-file.xml');
 *
 *     var simple = xPath('fizz', xml);
 *     simple; // 'fizz'
 *
 *     var list_values = xPath('foo/bar//baz', xml);
 *     list_values; // ['thing1', 'thing2']
 *
 *     var attribute_after_list = xPath('foo/bar//baz[1]/@what', xml);
 *     attribute_after_list; // test
 *
 */
function xPath(path, xmlFile) {
  var root = xmlFile.getRootElement();
  return xPathStep(path, root);
}


/**
 * Recursive path parsing - you probably want to use xPath instead of using
 * this function directly.
 */
function xPathStep(path, node) {
  // if node is an array, return the result for each entry
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    return node.map(function(singleNode) {
      return xPathStep(path, singleNode);
    });
  }

  if (!node) {
    return;
  }

  var nextNode, nodeValue;
  var paths = path.split('/');
  var firstChild = paths[0];
  var remainingPath = paths.slice(1).join('/');

  // if child ends with [\d] - find a list, return this index
  var indexMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/);
  var attributeMatch = firstChild.match(/@(\w+)/);

  if (indexMatch) {
    var tagName = indexMatch[1];
    var index = indexMatch[2];

    var children = node.getChildren(tagName);
    nextNode = children[index];
  } else if (firstChild === '') {
    // if another name is next, use as a matching tag (and remove from path)
    var tagName = '';
    if (paths.length > 1) {
      tagName = paths[1];
      remainingPath = paths.slice(2).join('/');
    }
    nextNode = node.getChildren(tagName);
  } else if (attributeMatch) {
    // @ means attribute
    var attributeName = attributeMatch[1];
    nodeValue = node.getAttribute(attributeName).getValue();
  } else {
    nextNode = node.getChild(firstChild);
  }

  var result;
  if (nodeValue) {
    result = nodeValue;
  } else if (remainingPath !== '') {
    result = xPathStep(remainingPath, nextNode);
  } else {
    result = nextNode.getText && nextNode.getText();
  }

  return result;
}


/**
 * Read a remote file at xmlFileUrl, parse it as xml, and
 * return an XMLService document object.
 */
function readRemoteXML(xmlFileUrl) {
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(xmlFileUrl).getContentText();
  return XmlService.parse(content);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem who was that with google sheet function calling myImportXml() answers aborted when the depth of xpath was over 2 .

The reason was the use of global variable for my array nextNodes[]
I replace it by adding an array return et send, between the recursives calls of the function. So my script no longer needs global variables end become the code below

I forgot to tell why i have recreated the existing google sheet function IMPORTXML !
IMPORTXML don't process with HTML page that don't validating XML enough.
So with my script we can operate modification on the xml document before parsing it and process the xPath research.

```
function myImportXml(url,path){
  if (url==null) url="http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/movie?media=mp4-lc&partner=YW5kcm9pZC12Mg&profile=large&version=2&code=265621"; // to test
  if (path==null) path="//nationality"; // to test
  var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
  var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
  var mynamespace=root.getNamespace();
  var items=xPathThrowDepthXml(path, root,mynamespace);
  return items;
}
function xPathThrowDepthXml(path, node,mynamespace,niveau,nextNodes,log) {
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185348/google-script-xml-parsing-error-cannot-find-function/58177338#58177338
   /* Retourne les texte et attribut selon le chemin xpath fourni, pour le noeud xml donné, avec son namespace
   TOUT ce qui est géré fonctionne ! :)
    tag[2], tag[@attrib] , rating[@note]/@note
    Sauts d'éléments, même dès la racine, 
    /tag1/tag2 ou //tag1/tag2 ou ///tag1/tag2  sont equivalents
    Syntaxes xpath comprises: tag[@class="meta-body-item"] , tag[contains(text(),"Nationalité")]/span
    un ou plusieurs points pour remonter dans la hierarchie    (tag1/.../title  tag1/./././title  sont équivalents )
    Ex de requette complexe qui est comprise: div[@class="meta-body-item"]/span[@class="light"][contains(text(),"Box Office")]/../span[2]
    Plus de variable ni tableau à déclarer globalement. Ceux ci sont maintenant envoyés récursivement et bidirectionnelement 
     Ainsi le script répond à un appel dune function de feuille de calcul
  */
  var nextNodesDebug,NodNamDebug,firstChild,nodeValues,tagName,paths,remainingPath
  var nextNodesCopi=nextNodes;var textWanted=null;
  if (niveau==null){
    niveau=-1;
    nextNodes=[];  
  }
  niveau++;
  if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau);
  nextNodes.push([]);
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {   // if node is an array, return the result for each entry - This does not seem to occur !
    return node.map(function(path,singleNode,mynamespace,niveau) {
      return xPathThrowDepthXml(path, singleNode,mynamespace,niveau,nextNodes,log);
    });
  }

  if (!node) {
    return;
  }
  paths = path.replace(/\/{3,}/g, "//").replace(/^\/{2,}/, "/").split('/');
  firstChild= paths [0];
  var firstChildDebug=firstChild;
  remainingPath = paths .slice(1).join('/');

  var indexMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/); //tag[2]  if child ends with [\d] - find a list, return this index

  var attributeMatch = firstChild.match(/^@(\w+)/); //  /@attribu  - to give the value of a named attribut
  var searchAttributeMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[@(\w+)\]/);  // tag[@attribu] - to give element having a named attribut 
  var searchAttributeEgalMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[@(\w+)=['"](.*)["']\]/);  // tag[@attribu] - to give element having a named attribut and a wanted value
  var searchTextContainsMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[contains\(text\(\),['"](.*)['"]\)\]/);  // tag[contains(text(),'Affiche')] - to give element having a wanted text

  if (indexMatch) {
    tagName = indexMatch[1];
    var index = indexMatch[2];
    var children = node.getChildren(tagName,mynamespace);
    nextNodesDebug=children[index];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
    nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);  
  } else if (firstChild === '') { // skiping element cases like newsList//title
    // if another name is next, use as a matching tag (and remove from path)
    tagName = '';
    if (paths.length > 1) {
      tagName = paths[1];

      remainingPath = paths.slice(2).join('/');
    }
    if (tagName.match(/(.*)\[/)) tagName=tagName.match(/(.*)\[/)[1];
    nextNodesDebug=node.getDescendants(); 
    for (var itag in nextNodesDebug){
      try{ var nodeName=nextNodesDebug[itag].getName();}catch(er){var nodeName="";}
      if (nodeName==tagName) {
        nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug[itag]);
      }
    }
  } else if (searchAttributeMatch) {// search the tagNAme element having a wanted atribut named attribNameWanted
    tagName = searchAttributeMatch[1];
    var attribNameWanted = searchAttributeMatch[2]; 
    var children= node.getChildren(tagName,mynamespace);
    for (var itag in children){
      if (children[itag].getName()==tagName){
        var nodeName=children[itag].getName();
        var attribs = children[itag].getAttributes(); 
        for (var iAtrib in attribs){
          if (attribs[iAtrib].getName()==attribNameWanted){ // here we have a tagNAme element having a wanted atribut named attribNameWanted
            nextNodesDebug=children[itag];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
            nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log("N"+nextNodes[niveau]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }  else if (searchAttributeEgalMatch) {// search the tagNAme element having a wanted attribut named attribNameWanted  that have the value valueAttribWanted
    tagName = searchAttributeEgalMatch[1];
    var attribNameWanted = searchAttributeEgalMatch[2]; 
    var valueAttribWanted = searchAttributeEgalMatch[3]; 
    var children= node.getChildren(tagName,mynamespace);
    for (var itag in children){
      if (children[itag].getName()==tagName){
        var nodeName=children[itag].getName();
        var attribs = children[itag].getAttributes(); 
        for (var iAtrib in attribs){
          if (attribs[iAtrib].getName()==attribNameWanted){ // here we have a tagNAme element having a wanted attribut named attribNameWanted  that have the value valueAttribWanted
            var atval=attribs[iAtrib].getValue();
            if(attribs[iAtrib].getValue()==valueAttribWanted){
              nextNodesDebug=children[itag];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
              nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log("N"+nextNodes[niveau]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (attributeMatch) {
    // @ means attribute
    var parent=node.getParentElement().getName();
    var attributeName = attributeMatch[1];
    //Logger.log("niv"+niveau);Logger.log("nod"+node.getDescendants())
    var nodeValuesDebug=""
    try{ nodeValuesDebug=node.getAttribute(attributeName).getValue();}catch(er){}
    nodeValues=nodeValuesDebug;

  } else if (  firstChild.split(".").length-1==firstChild.length) { // firsChild=="." or ".." or .....  -> go up one or more levels
    var parent=node
      for (var n=0;n<firstChild.length;n++){
      parent=parent.getParentElement();
    }
    nextNodes[niveau].push(parent);
  } else {
    // simple child to search - But we must try to find children
    textWanted=null;
    if (searchTextContainsMatch){ // if we must finding element having a wanted text
      firstChild=searchTextContainsMatch[1];
      textWanted=searchTextContainsMatch[2];
    }
    var children= node.getChildren(firstChild,mynamespace);
    if (children.length!=0){
      for (var itag in children){
        if (children[itag].getName()==firstChild){  // &&itag<3 limitation can be added here for degug purposes
          nextNodesDebug=children[itag];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
          if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"nextNodpush"+itag+NodNamDebug);
          if (textWanted==null){
            nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log(niveau+"->Nodes"+nextNodes[niveau]);  
          }
          if (children[itag].getText()==textWanted){
            nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log(niveau+"->Nodes"+nextNodes[niveau]);  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var result=[];

  if (nodeValues) {
    result.push(nodeValues);
  }
  else{
    if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"for nextNode"+nextNodes[niveau].length);
    for (var inextNode in nextNodes[niveau]){
      if (remainingPath !== '') {

          var mem=xPathThrowDepthXml(remainingPath, nextNodes[niveau][inextNode],mynamespace,niveau,nextNodes,log)
          nextNodes=mem[1]
          if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"Result.PUSH MEM"+mem[0]);
          if (mem!="") result.push(mem[0]);

      } else {
        var inextNodeTextDebug=""
        if (nextNodes[niveau][inextNode]!=null) { 
          inextNodeTextDebug=nextNodes[niveau][inextNode].getText && nextNodes[niveau][inextNode].getText();
          if (inextNodeTextDebug!=null)result.push(inextNodeTextDebug);
          if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"Result.pushTEXT="+inextNodeTextDebug);
        }
      }
    }
    nextNodes[niveau].pop();
  }
  if (niveau==0){return result
  } else {
    return [result,nextNodes]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tanks a lot for your function that worked so for me that i continue to develop it and i come back here to share my work

I wanted that function can undersand more path syntaxe elements like:
//tag
tag1/./title
tag2/.../title
tag[@attrib='value']
tag[contains(text(),'foo']
So i must use array to keep informations send and return between depth processed by  this recursive function.

Because i am french my comments in my script are in french.
Sorry, but i hop t hat my contribution will help some developpers to use xpath in google script
If work perfectli in my google app script interface, but i have a problem since google sheet function to calls myImportXml(): I think i have no answers when the depth of xpath is over 2 !! :(

```
var nextNodes;var log=0; // variables globales necessaires à la function xPathThrowDepthXml
    function myImportXml(url,path){
      nextNodes=[]; // table à déclarer globalement
      if (url==null) url="http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/movie?media=mp4-lc&partner=YW5kcm9pZC12Mg&profile=large&version=2&code=265621"; // to test
      if (path==null) path="//nationality"; // to test
      var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
      var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
      var mynamespace=root.getNamespace();
      var items=xPathThrowDepthXml(path, root,mynamespace);
      return items;
    }
    function xPathThrowDepthXml(path, node,mynamespace,niveau) {
       /* Retourne les texte et attribut selon le chemin xpath fourni, pour le noeud xml donné, avec son namespace
       TOUT ce qui est géré fonctionne ! :)
        Sauts d'éléments, même dès la racine, tag[2], tag[@attrib] , rating[@note]/@note
        /tag1/tag2 ou //tag1/tag2 ou ///tag1/tag2  sont equivalents
        Syntaxes xpath comprises: tag[@class="meta-body-item"] , tag[contains(text(),"Nationalité")]/span
        un ou plusieurs points pour remonter dans la hierarchie    (tag1/.../title  tag1/./././title  sont équivalents )
        Ex de requette complexe qui est comprise: div[@class="meta-body-item"]/span[@class="light"][contains(text(),"Box Office")]/../span[2]
      */
      var nextNodesDebug,NodNamDebug,firstChild,nodeValues,tagName,paths,remainingPath
      var nextNodesCopi=nextNodes;var textWanted=null;
      if (niveau==null)niveau=-1;
      niveau++;
      if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau);
      nextNodes.push([]); // Faudrait vérifier si on ajoute pas trop de push que de niveaux !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      if (Array.isArray(node)) {   // if node is an array, return the result for each entry  Ne semble pas agir
        return node.map(function(path,singleNode,mynamespace,niveau) {
          return xPathThrowDepthXml(path, singleNode,mynamespace,niveau);
        });
      }

      if (!node) {
        return;
      }
      paths = path.replace(/\/{3,}/g, "//").replace(/^\/{2,}/, "/").split('/');
      //paths = path.split('/');
      firstChild= paths [0];
      var firstChildDebug=firstChild;
      remainingPath = paths .slice(1).join('/');

      // if child ends with [\d] - find a list, return this index
      var indexMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/); //tag[2]
      var attributeMatch = firstChild.match(/^@(\w+)/); //  /@attribu pour avoir la valeur de tel attribut
      var searchAttributeMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[@(\w+)\]/);  // tag[@attribu] Pour avoir l'element possédant un attribut nommé d'une telle  façon
      var searchAttributeEgalMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[@(\w+)=['"](.*)["']\]/);  // tag[@attribu] Pour avoir l'element possédant un attribut nommé d'une telle  façon et ayant telle valeure
      var searchTextContainsMatch = firstChild.match(/(\w+)\[contains\(text\(\),['"](.*)['"]\)\]/);  // tag[contains(text(),'Affiche')] Pour avoir l'element dont le texte est telle chaîne

      if (indexMatch) {
        tagName = indexMatch[1];
        var index = indexMatch[2];
        var children = node.getChildren(tagName,mynamespace);
        nextNodesDebug=children[index];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
        nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);  
      } else if (firstChild === '') { // Cas des saut d'elements par comme newsList//title
        // if another name is next, use as a matching tag (and remove from path)
        tagName = '';
        if (paths.length > 1) {
          tagName = paths[1];

          remainingPath = paths.slice(2).join('/');
        }
        if (tagName.match(/(.*)\[/)) tagName=tagName.match(/(.*)\[/)[1];
        //nextNodesDebug=node.getChildren(tagName,mynamespace);
        nextNodesDebug=node.getDescendants(); //if (nextNodesDebug=="") 
        //NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
        for (var itag in nextNodesDebug){
          try{ var nodeName=nextNodesDebug[itag].getName();}catch(er){var nodeName="";}
          if (nodeName==tagName) {
            nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug[itag]);
          }
        }
      } else if (searchAttributeMatch) {// cherche l'element tagName ayant un attribut nommé attribNameWanted
        tagName = searchAttributeMatch[1];
        var attribNameWanted = searchAttributeMatch[2]; 
        var children= node.getChildren(tagName,mynamespace);
        for (var itag in children){
          if (children[itag].getName()==tagName){
            var nodeName=children[itag].getName();
            var attribs = children[itag].getAttributes(); 
            for (var iAtrib in attribs){
              if (attribs[iAtrib].getName()==attribNameWanted){ // on tient là un élément nommé tagName dont l'attribut est nommé attribNameWanted
                nextNodesDebug=children[itag];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
                nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log("N"+nextNodes[niveau]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }  else if (searchAttributeEgalMatch) {// cherche l'element tagName ayant un attribut nommé attribNameWanted 
        tagName = searchAttributeEgalMatch[1];
        var attribNameWanted = searchAttributeEgalMatch[2]; 
        var valueAttribWanted = searchAttributeEgalMatch[3]; 
        var children= node.getChildren(tagName,mynamespace);
        for (var itag in children){
          if (children[itag].getName()==tagName){
            var nodeName=children[itag].getName();
            var attribs = children[itag].getAttributes(); 
            for (var iAtrib in attribs){
              if (attribs[iAtrib].getName()==attribNameWanted){ // on tient là un élément nommé tagName dont l'attribut est nommé attribNameWanted
                var atval=attribs[iAtrib].getValue();
                if(attribs[iAtrib].getValue()==valueAttribWanted){
                  nextNodesDebug=children[itag];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
                  nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log("N"+nextNodes[niveau]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else if (attributeMatch) {
        // @ means attribute
        var parent=node.getParentElement().getName();
        var attributeName = attributeMatch[1];
        //Logger.log("niv"+niveau);Logger.log("nod"+node.getDescendants())
        var nodeValuesDebug=""
        try{ nodeValuesDebug=node.getAttribute(attributeName).getValue();}catch(er){}
        nodeValues=nodeValuesDebug;

      } else if (  firstChild.split(".").length-1==firstChild.length) { // firsChild=="." ou ".." ou .....  ->Remonter d'autant de niveaux
        var parent=node
          for (var n=0;n<firstChild.length;n++){
          parent=parent.getParentElement();
        }
        nextNodes[niveau].push(parent);
      } else {
        // simple child to search - Mais il faut plutôt try de chercher des children si has children !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        textWanted=null;
        if (searchTextContainsMatch){
          firstChild=searchTextContainsMatch[1];
          textWanted=searchTextContainsMatch[2];
        }
        var children= node.getChildren(firstChild,mynamespace);
        if (children.length!=0){
          for (var itag in children){
            if (children[itag].getName()==firstChild){  // &&itag<3 LIMITATION POUR LE DEBOGADE (A RETIRER)
              nextNodesDebug=children[itag];NodNamDebug=nextNodesDebug.getName();
              if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"nextNodpush"+itag+NodNamDebug);
              if (textWanted==null){
                nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log(niveau+"->Nodes"+nextNodes[niveau]);  
              }
              if (children[itag].getText()==textWanted){
                nextNodes[niveau].push(nextNodesDebug);//Logger.log(niveau+"->Nodes"+nextNodes[niveau]);  
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      var result=[];

      if (nodeValues) {
        result.push(nodeValues);
      }
      else{
        if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"for nextNode"+nextNodes[niveau].length);
        for (var inextNode in nextNodes[niveau]){
          if (remainingPath !== '') {

              var mem=xPathThrowDepthXml(remainingPath, nextNodes[niveau][inextNode],mynamespace,niveau)
              if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"Result.PUSH MEM"+mem);
              if (mem!="") result.push(mem); // Pb: Multiplie les reponse pour mediaList/media/title

          } else {
            var inextNodeTextDebug=""
            if (nextNodes[niveau][inextNode]!=null) { 
              inextNodeTextDebug=nextNodes[niveau][inextNode].getText && nextNodes[niveau][inextNode].getText();
              if (inextNodeTextDebug!=null)result.push(inextNodeTextDebug);
              if (log==3) Logger.log(niveau+"Result.pushTEXT="+inextNodeTextDebug);
            }
          }
        }
        nextNodes[niveau].pop();
      }
      return result;
    }
```